# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: , json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes:

Tags: python, json, python-jsonschema

Hi I am working with JSON in my file in Python:

```
import json
userData = '''[
{
    "userID" : "20",
    "devices" : {
        "360020000147343433313337" : "V33_03",
        "3f0026001747343438323536" : "Door_03",
        "170035001247343438323536" : "IR_06",
        "28004c000651353530373132" : "BED_17"
    }
},

]'''

info = json.loads(userData)
```

I get this error when I load it:
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value:

or sometimes when I add something:
 json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `ast` module

**Ex:**

```
import ast
userData = '''[
{
    "userID" : "20",
    "devices" : {
        "360020000147343433313337" : "V33_03",
        "3f0026001747343438323536" : "Door_03",
        "170035001247343438323536" : "IR_06",
        "28004c000651353530373132" : "BED_17"
    }
},
]'''

info = ast.literal_eval(userData)
print(info)
```

Comment: Is this a JSON object now?

Comment: What do you mean by JSON object? using `ast` converts your string data-structure to valid python data-type..like a `dict` same as `json.loads`

Comment: I can get objects by info['userID'] ?, Yeah just tested it, I can go for this. However, still wondering that didn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Looks the format is incorrect.

```
userData = '''[
{
    "userID" : "20",
    "devices" : {
        "360020000147343433313337" : "V33_03",
        "3f0026001747343438323536" : "Door_03",
        "170035001247343438323536" : "IR_06",
        "28004c000651353530373132" : "BED_17"
    }
},  <--- remove this ","

]'''
```

See my test:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('[{"a":"b"}]')
[{u'a': u'b'}]
>>> json.loads('[{"a":"b"},]')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, below how to get the JSON content or to get some spam:

```
import requests


url = 'http://httpbin.org/status/200'
r = requests.get(url)

if 'json' in r.headers.get('Content-Type'):
    js = r.json()
else:
    print('Response content is not in JSON format.')
    js = 'spam'
```

Comment: Does this help with the original question? (identifying the problem within the JSON string)

Answer (score 0):

With your example as-is and no further understanding:
`info = json.loads(json.dumps(userData))` will work.

There are a lot of posts on SO about python multi-line strings and JSON. Ideally you would not be loading a string from a string variable that way is the general comment you will see.

With some additional explanation, such as where does the data originate and in what format, I can provide additional assistance.